# Retrieving Android Contacts

Tags: android, contacts, contactscontract

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        String id = cur.getString(
        cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        String name = cur.getString(
        cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

        if (name.equals(selected) && Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {

            Cursor pCur = cr.query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " =?", new String[] {
                id
            }, null);
            finalsend = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;
            while (pCur.moveToNext()) {

            }
            pCur.close();

        }
```

The code is supposed to look through contacts to find one that matches the "selected" variable which appears to work fine but then it is supposed to switch to the `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI` and find the same contact by matching up the ID's and give me the phone number saved for that contact.

Every time it returns "Data1", what am I doing wrong? It's probably a stupid mistake but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code snippet is working for me:

```
String id , name;
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

     String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

     Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,  null, null, null, sortOrder);



      if (cur.getCount() > 0) {


            while (cur.moveToNext()) {



                id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                name = cur.getString( cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                Log.i(tag, "Id is "+ id+"\t Name is"+name);

            if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0){                      


                        Cursor pCur = cr.query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,

                            null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", new String[]{id}, null);



                        while (pCur.moveToNext()) {


                // Do something with phones



                       int phNumber = pCur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

                       String phn = pCur.getString(phNumber);

                       Log.i("phn number",  phn);



                    } 

                    pCur.close();

                }

                }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much. the part I was missing was `int phNumber = pCur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);`